# How do you determine the vector coordinates of a radial vector on a curve when given the tangent angle and radius?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given a curved line, and any point on that line is a radial vector with only a known radius $r$ and known tangent angle $a$, how does one express the point $(r,a)$ as vector coordinates $(x, y)$?

I have a spiral defined by its changing tangent angle and radius.  I want to know the angle from any given point $(r,a)$ to the $x$ axis (the $\arg(x+iy)$ on the complex plane for instance) or the vector coordinates $(x,y)$ that corresponds to point $(r,a)$, as either will provide the other.

[Click here to view the geometric representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn2Ke.jpg)

The usual method for finding the tangent angle $a$ of a radial vector follows

$$\tan(a)=r(dr/d \arg(z))^{-1}.$$  However, on the complex plane for this curve/spiral, the argument of $z$ cancels out entirely (in how $r$ is defined), such that the antiderivative of $d\arg(z)$,

$$\int jt^{-1} dt=\arg(z),$$

is multivalued (in multiples of the inverse of the real part of $z$), as the integral $$-\int_{1}^{e^k} jt^{-1} dt=\arg(z): k=e^{\arg(z)/j} $$ is indeterminant: $$j \ln(e^{arg(z)/j}) = j, e^{\arg(z)/j}>=0.$$

Yet, there is a single argument of $z$, it's just that I  do not know how to solve for it even given the radius and the tangent angle.  This is not an Archimedean spiral in that the angle changes per a constant value and it is not quite a logarithmic spiral either (somewhere between the two).  So if the spiral could be thought of as a particle curling in a field toward zero, it would be accelerating...not having a constant radial speed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a particle starting from the center
 at t=0. The angular position of the particle is given by $\theta=\omega t$, where $\omega$ is a constant. We also have a change in radial distance (radial speed) $\dot{r}=u$ where $u$ is a constant. Now the position in the xy-plane at time t is given by

$$\mathbf{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t))=(ut\cos(\omega t), ut\sin(\omega t))$$

[image: Spiral t=0 to 10, $u=1$ $\omega=2$]

Spiral t=0 to 9, $u=1$,  $\omega=2$

Edit: It seems you edited your question while I was answering, hence no mention of the complex plane, but I think you can still use the information to figure out what to do :)

The $(r,a)$ point z is

$$z=x+iy=r(\cos a, i\sin a)$$

Comment: I was trying to get more specific by editing in order to get wording so as to attract individuals who only pick up on keywords regarding the complex plane.  Your answer applies to both, so i am going to re-edit to change the wording back to what it was.  I will then check your answer, but it looks really good.

Comment: I appreciate your time!  Unfortunately it describes a specific case only (an Archimedian spiral, where the spacing between each cycle is constant).  Any thoughts on how one might apply this to the general cases (i.e. any curved line), hyperbolic spiral, logarithmic spiral, etc.?  In other words, it doesn't give me my solution, as the spiral I am working with is not Archimedean...and I do not know exactly what it is until I can solve for the angle in question.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you need. Maybe you can include your problem in the question. If you dont have a suitable parametrization $\mathbf{r}(t)$ of your spiral you can always solve the differentials to get one. 

The relations between the angle a and the rectangular coordinates (x,y) are $$a=\arctan (\frac{y}{x})$$ using a suitable branch.

$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: I added more of the problem in the question.  Hope that helps.